# How can I populate a 100,000,000 element array?

Tags: java, arrays

I was thinking of storing a random number in each element using a loop. Is there a better way to do this? I need random numbers to test my sorts and the timing.

Comment: I'm not really sure what other options there would be; if you need 100,000,000 random numbers, you need 100,000,000 random numbers. Although I would have phrased it "... use a loop to store a random number in each ..."

Comment: I am sure you will end up into a performance hit in this program :(. Think about you setting up the data in the array, then running comparison on each element and finally updating the array. Just a concern to worry about later.

Comment: Just do it in the standard way. 100000000 is not that big these days.

Comment: Store the random numbers in the data structure on which your sort works. Most probably an array

Comment: Do you want the numbers inside the array to be unique? This should bring up some interesting solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple pseudocode:

```
int[] random = new int[10000000];

for (int i = 0; i < random.length; i++) {
   random[i] = generateAbsoluteRandom();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be a different random set each time?  If not, generate one random array of the size you need, serialize it, and store it.  The load it in when you need it.  That might run faster.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is going to be the best:

- Allocate the large array
- For each element

  - Generate random number
  - Assign to element.

The bottleneck will be the calls to the random number generator, and you cannot avoid those ... if you want random numbers.

Just write the code in a simple fashion and let the JIT compiler worry about optimizing it.  Only get involved if profiling your application reveals that this part of your application is a significant performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go to multithreading. The size of the array should warrant the cost of creating threads.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SimpleTest implements Runnable {

    public static int[] array = new int[1000];
    private int startPoint;

    public SimpleTest(int startPoint) {
        this.startPoint = startPoint;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread test1 = new Thread(new SimpleTest(0));
        Thread test2 = new Thread(new SimpleTest(1));
        test1.start(); test2.start();
        while(test1.isAlive() || test2.isAlive()) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
        }
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }

    public void run() {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = startPoint; i < array.length; i+=2) {
            array[i] = r.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Thread "+(startPoint+1)+" has put a value no. "+i+" and it was: "+array[i]);
        }
    }   

}
```

**EDIT**
Hmm, i checked execution times and there's no improvement on my double cored machine. It seems that the the size of an array does not warrant the cost of creating threads, or i'm missing something else here.

**EDIT2**
When i split it on 8 threads (;P) the improvement was quite big - i went down form starting ~3900ms to ~2500. There's something onto this...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to store the values? If you set the seed value, you will get the same sequence of values from random.

> Random r = Random(856007); // or any number to identify a given sequence
>
> n = r.nextInt();

Comment: For test purposes, for example, testing the run time of a sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I've not bothered to test whether this is an actual speedup, but you could consider making a `ByteBuffer` of the correct size (4 bytes * 100000000 elements), and then fill it with [Random.nextBytes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextBytes%28byte%5B%5D%29).  From there, call [asIntBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#asIntBuffer%28%29) on it and you will get a buffer full of integers.

I have proved neither that this is faster nor that it does not affect the distribution of your results - but if you are actually looking for speed, you could try it out.